# Effectively Stopping ServerSockets

Tags: java, networking

I'm new to networking and I've been playing around with sockets in Java. I was wondering what the best way is to stop a ServerSocket. With my current code, I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at io.bluecube.worldlink.DataListener.run(DataListener.java:35) //<------------------------
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[13:30:50] [pool-4-thread-1/WARN]:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error points to this line in my DataListener class:

```
public class DataListener implements Runnable{

private ServerSocket socket;

public DataListener(ServerSocket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        try {
            Socket receive = socket.accept(); //<---- Error
     //stuff
```

This runnable runs in a thread pool. Currently I shut down everything with the following:

```
private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

//stuff

public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException{
    pool.shutdownNow();
    if (!serverSocket.isClosed()){
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch(IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
        System.out.println("Terminated");
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of shutting this down? Thanks!

Comment: That way is as good as any, and quicker and less CPU-wasteful than the best alternative of setting a short timeout and checking a boolean every time it triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to answer:

> Is there a better way of shutting this down?

Do not use `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` as your condition because it is not reliable.

***Why?***

First, see (read) the [ExecutorService API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), for `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()` it states:

> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use awaitTermination to do that.

And additionally for `shutdownNow()`:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

So, calling `pool.shutdownNow();` may or may not have an (immediate) effect. It is also a non-blocking call which means that `this.serverSocket.close();` may get executed before any other thread continues to execute.

***It may also happen*** that thread A evaluates `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and then gets suspended to let thread B continue. Thread B runs your `shutdown()` method closing (!) the `serverSocket`. When thread A resumes your `serverSocket` is closed. - ***you should not assume any particular execution order.***

You simply do not know / control when your `DataListener` threads will be interrupted. In fact, depending on your implementation (`//stuff`) they may never be interrupted at all.

***So what now?***

- Instead of sharing your `serverSocket` between multiple threads pass the new `Socket` instance which you get from your `serverSocket.accept()` to your `DataListener` threads.
- Keep your `serverSocket` in the same class (thread) as your `shutdown()` method together with your "while-true-loop" blocking on `serverSocket.accept()`:

  `pool.execute(new DataListener(serverSocket.accept()));`
- (Consider defining a timeout for your `serverSocket`.)

In this way you spin up a `DataListener` thread only for a already connected `Socket` instance. Do your `// stuff` with that connection and then close that `Socket` instance in that thread.

```
public class DataListener implements Runnable {

    private final Socket receive;

    public DataListener(final Socket receive){
        this.receive = receive;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff with your connected socket
        // do proper resource/exception handling
        // close the socket here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, unless specified otherwise, the `accept()` method will block indefinitely. So, yeah, closing the socket while `accept()` is blocking will cause the problem you see.

So start off by calling `setSoTimeout()` on your `ServerSocket`. This will have the effect of making `accept()` only block for N milliseconds... after this it will throw a `SocketTimeoutException` which you will have to handle, but this allows you to effectively put this into a loop - simply resubmit your `Runnable` at the end of each run. If the pool has been shut down, you will be unable to resubmit it, and you'll know you're done.

Next, after you call `shutdown()` on the pool, you will need to wait for the pool to actually shut down. Use `awaitTermination()` on the pool for that, and then you can close the `ServerSocket`.

There are, of course, many variations on this - you could keep your `while()` loop and have some sort of flag set, etc -- whatever you're most comfortable with. The outline I provide above is just the first thing to come to my mind and it may not be perfect for you, but hopefully will show you the way.